# mailto raising exception when no default mail application

Tags: vb.net

As simply in subject i am using mailto function within my taskdialog messageboxes that user can click it and mail if he decided to. Unfortunetly if there is no default email client on system - i tested on new brain windows 7 installation then i am receiving error. Do you know how to overcome that iccue or replace this to something else?

```
AddHandler dialog.HyperlinkClick, Sub()
Process.Start("mailto:" & "someemail@domain.com.pl")
End Sub
```

Error when no default email program:
`System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005`)

Comment: Pretty much everyone using a computer will have an email client so I would simply catch the exception.

Comment: you mean within AddHandler Sub ?

Comment: There's only one place that you're calling `Process.Start` so there's only one place that it can throw an exception, so there's only one place you can catch that exception.